# How to handle error of facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am working on facebook integration in an android app. I did a lot of search about error handling of facebook inn android but nothing foung. Can anyone tell me how handle these situation in  android :

**1.The user changes her password which invalidates the access token.
2.The user de-authorizes your app.
3.The user logs out of Facebook.**

My code of facebook integration is here :

```
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };



    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (   exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException ||
                exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException) 
        {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainWindow.this)
                    .setTitle("cancel")
                    .setMessage("your permission has expired.")
                    .setPositiveButton("ok", null)
                    .show();

        } 

    }




private void onClickFacebookRequest() 
 {
        if (session.isOpened()) 
        {
            sendRequests();

        } else {
            StatusCallback callback = new StatusCallback() {
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                    if (exception != null) {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainWindow.this)
                                .setTitle(R.string.login_failed_dialog_title)
                                .setMessage(exception.getMessage())
                                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_button, null)
                                .show();
                     session = createSession();
                    }
                }
            };
            pendingRequest = true;


            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(callback));
        }
    }
 private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
 private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";

 private void sendRequests() 
 {

     List<String> permissions = quytechApps.getSession().getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            pendingRequest = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            return;
        }

        showValidationDialog("Please Wait.posting Data on Facebook");
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.splash_screen_final4);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

        Bundle postParams=new Bundle();
        postParams.putByteArray("photo",byteArray);
        postParams.putString("message", "Hi Friends I am using Twinqli Chat App.");

        Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/photos", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback()
        {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // showPublishResult(getString(R.string.photo_post), response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
            if(response.getError() == null)
            {
                Log.d("GraphApiSample.java Sucesses","sucess");
                dismissValidatingDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                dismissValidatingDialog();
                session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                //quytechApps.getSession().
                //quytechApps.setSession(null);
//                  Log.d("GraphApiSample.java",""+response.getError().getErrorMessage());
            }

            }

        });
        request.executeAsync();
 }

 private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
        for (String string : subset) {
            if (!superset.contains(string)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

 static final String applicationId = "390611174384274";
 boolean pendingRequest;
 static final String PENDING_REQUEST_BUNDLE_KEY = "com.facebook.samples.graphapi:PendingRequest";

 private Session createSession() 
 {
        Session activeSession = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (activeSession == null || activeSession.getState().isClosed()) 
        {
            activeSession = new Session.Builder(this).setApplicationId(applicationId).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(activeSession);
        }
        return activeSession;
    }

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (qsession.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data) &&
                pendingRequest &&
                session.getState().isOpened()) {
            sendRequests();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        pendingRequest = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(PENDING_REQUEST_BUNDLE_KEY, pendingRequest);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putBoolean(PENDING_REQUEST_BUNDLE_KEY, pendingRequest);
    }
```

can anyone help me . Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are  using `facebook-api` i guess ?

Comment: right. i am using facebook-api for android.

Comment: Does my answer below help you ?

Answer (score 2):

The `handleError()` method noted by Ming Li is relevant to request errors. It does not handle login errors. I have not seen any examples in the Facebook docs, nor samples, as to how to handle login errors, beyond differentiating between a cancellation and an error. My suggestion is to generate erroneous conditions prior to login attempts (e.g. change the password, deauthorize the app, etc), then in the login callback look at the different values you get for error.getMessage(), and build your own mechanisms accordingly (e.g. if the word "session" appears in the message, tell the user to login to the Facebook app). Also note that getLocalizedMessage() seems not to work (as of SDK 3.5.2). You can differentiate between cancels and errors by `if (exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException)` and `if (exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException)`, but that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

This question is related to face book error handling and is very complex to handle .

However, when i was using the face book API, i got a list of error codes that might be returned and as a result i was able to gracefully solve this scenario . I guess what you are asking for , is graceful error handling.

First of all if it is so, a search in google reveals this [url](https://www.google.com/#safe=active&sclient=psy-ab&q=facebook+api+error+handling&oq=Facebook+error+handling+&gs_l=hp.1.1.0i22i30l4.684385.689390.0.695159.24.23.0.0.0.1.397.2603.13j8j1j1.23.0.epsugrpqhmsignedin,hmss2=false...0...1.1.22.psy-ab..2.22.2322.D0FSaFn3yIE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49784469,d.aWc,pv.xjs.s.en_US.MpiVkF51mpA.O&fp=dbd40e074ea0c8e1&biw=1280&bih=911).

Now off to the fun part :

**Invalidation of access token :** Here the error description is : Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token and the error number returned is : 190

**User De authorirization :** This is a permission issue, so error desc is : Permissions error and error no is : 200

**User logs out :** When user logs out, it will lead to user data error . The error desc is : User data  failure and error no is : 310.

But, there are other scenarios as well, which you need to consider. For this you can get a list of all these error codes here in this [LINK](http://www.fb-developers.info/tech/fb_dev/faq/general/gen_10.html) .

Answer (score 0):

The error handling document is here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/

You should also look at the Scrumptious sample app, specifically the handleError() method in SelectionFragment.java, it breaks down the different cases you should handle.